# Groupoid element with multiple inverse elements?

Tags: inverse, groupoids

Simply put, is there a groupoid whose element can have multiple inverse elements? I know how to prove that elements of a semigroup have unique inverses, but this is a bit different... If there is such a groupoid, can someone give an example?

Answer (score 1):

No. An inverse of $a$ is an element $b$ such that $cab=c,abc'=c',dba=d,$ and $bad'=d'$ whenever those elements are defined. But then if $b'$ is another inverse, $b'ab=b'=b$. In face this shows more generally that in a "monoidoid," where every element need not have an inverse, having a left and a right inverse is equivalent to being invertible, so that the left and right inverses must coincide.

Comment: A monoidoid is just a category. There's no reason for this horrible double oid terminology.

Comment: In the final step you are using the associative property... that would work for a semigroup, not a groupoid...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan it was a bit of a joke, hence the scare quotes. Knight1805, groupoids are associative whenever the multiplication is defined.

Comment: @Knight1805: "groupoid" has two meanings, one of which is relatively uncommon (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)) and one of which is as a particular kind of category (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid). Kevin refers to the second notion.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan oh, good catch! Knight1805, if you meant the meaning that's the same as "magma," I'll delete this.